# Practical usage of Automotive BMS with Active Balancing

Tags: lithium-ion, automotive, bms, cell-balancing

I work as an intern at one of top semiconductor companies and also in automotive industry. Since I'm assigned to BMS (Battery Management System) team as a concept engineer I'm constantly looking for new ideas and possible improvements of the current products available on the market. I recently started on researching various topologies on so called active balancing - distributing excess charge of cells with too high voltage to the ones with lowest voltage in a string of cells.

At first sight this seemed as "must have" feature for future generations of current product but later didn't seem much of a good idea since currently used Li-Ion battery cells (or its variants) have relatively flat characteristic and shouldn't deviate much. If there is not much difference between cell with the highest and lowest voltage, then this functionality doesn't really pay off. Even if one could design such a device with very high efficiency.

**Is a BMS capable of active balancing (based on switched capacitor topology) worth even a tiny bit of considering for future implementation (in form of integrated circuit) or should this idea be abandoned once and for all?** It looks like Li-Ion batteries with this kind of characteristic are going to be most used ones in automotive for a long time.

**Are there any other industries where realizing such functionality might be a better idea than for automotive battery packs?** Idea of active balancing is pretty old but not much development has been put into it. I feel like capacitor based one (instead of bulky, heavy and expensive transfomer based counterpart) could achieve high efficiency while keeping design relatively simple. But if there is no applications, where one could really shine then there is no point designing in one, is it?

**P.S.:** This question is more of asking for an advice from experienced folks around here and not a technical one.

Comment: I think this should go by experimenting on a system with active balancing VS the same system without active balancing. Then, compare the results and decide.

Comment: You should probably try to quantify how much the currently used cells deviate, also in regards of aging. Without this data it's a guessing game how much you could benefit from active balancing. Perfectly matched cells wouldn't need balancing at all.

Comment: Losing heat through balancing resistors in passive balancer BMS is far easier than waiting for the active balancers to charge the pack up to full voltage. Other topologies of active balancing do not perform any better either. Plus, they require bulky capacitors that increase the board's width and height, and it's something that no one prefers for simple reasons.

Comment: And Lars Hankeln's answer also provides an excellent point.